# Cypress - Increment a field by one each time?

Tags: cypress

I have some automation in Cypress that I want to essentially increment by one each times it's ran, I want to add it to a pipeline so it's ran daily, my code is:

```js
cy.get('publicField').click().type('Day 1')
```

So when it's ran again it's day 2, day 3, etc..

What would be the best way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: what CI tool you would be using ?

Comment: I was thinking CircleCi

Answer (score 2):

One way, set your start date in a fixture and calculate the difference to current date.

I would add the [Day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference) package for that, but you could also do it with plain javascript.

**start-date.json**

```js
"2022-03-09"
```

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

it('types todays sequence day', () => {

  cy.fixture('start-date.json').then(start => {

    const date1 = dayjs(start)
    const date2 = dayjs(Date.now())
    const diffDays = date2.diff(date1, 'day')

    cy.get('publicField').type(`Day ${diffDays}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were only running your code once daily, a possible solution would just be to generate the date that the test is ran.

```js
cy.get('foo')
  .click()
  .type(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
  // The above creates a string that is something like 20220309 (YYYYMMDD).
  // You could play around with formatting for the Date string to suit your needs.
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work on this as I need it to count up, so the moment i start it would be 1 and the end would be infinite until i stop it really.

Comment: The whole idea of it really is to be day 1, day 2, day 3, etc :)

Comment: Why do you need it to count up specfically? The answer you're looking for is going to require CI setup, so if you don't have one selected yet, you're not going to be able to achieve this yet.

Comment: "answer you're looking for" as in having something external from the test suite keeping track of some index -> that'd be something that the CI _could_ store for you, but it'll still be _somewhat_ tricky

Comment: Thanks - yeah i was thinking of something external